# How can I test multiple values in one expression in python

Tags: python

Is this the correct way to test if multiple variables exist in one line:

```
for line in csvf:
    if line[14] and line[10] and line[14] in line[10]:
        print(line[10],line[14])
```

I normally do this:

```
for line in csvf:
    if line[14]:
        if line[10]:
            if line[14] in line[10]:
                print(line[10],line[14])
```

is there a limit to how many variables you can test in one expression/line?

Comment: You might also consider the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in: `if all([line[14], line[10], line[14] in line[10]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is a perfectly fine way of doing what you're doing; it's more concise and readable than the second. There's no practical limit to how many expressions you can `and` together in one expression, but if you really have lots then that might be a sign you could be doing something better.

Actually, just to be extra clear you might want to use brackets:

```
if line[14] and line[10] and (line[14] in line[10]):
```